# Open card after certain time

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

i'm programming a blackjack (single thread) for a university project and the dealer is the computer (e.g. no player action)...

Does someone know how can I program in Java something like this:

```
while (dealerpoints < 17)
    open card and repaint frame
    wait 1 sec (to run again the condition test for while)
```

THe thing is, I don't want all dealer cards painted at once...

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel Sotero

UPDATE: this is my code (that doesn't work)

```
        while (Dealer.getInstance().dealerPoints < 17){

            Dealer.getInstance().openCard();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){ }
        }
```

openCard declaration:

```
    private void openCard(){

        Card temp;

        temp = Deck.getInstance().myPop();
        Dealer.getInstance().cards.add(temp);
        Dealer.getInstance().dealerPoints += temp.getValue(); 
        MainPanel.getInstance().updateDealerLabel(Dealer.getInstance().dealerPoints);
        MainPanel.getInstance().repaint();

    }
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? The drawing, the waiting, something else?

Comment: You will want to use a timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Thanks @sorifiend, but I couldn't figure it out how to use it...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta the waiting... If there is no 'time' involved it works fine

Comment: @sorifiend Better to use `javax.swing.Timer` as it executes the call back in the EDT

Comment: @GabrielSotero You need to clarify you question.  Are you using Swing/AWT or the console.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am sorry. I'm using swing... I've edited my first post with my tentative (which does not work) code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't block the Event Dispatching Thread as it is responsible for (amongst other things) processing re-paint requests.  So all the time you're waiting, the UI is not begin updated.  This includes using loops and `Thread#sleep`.

One solution is to use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), but, it's unreliable in terms of when it will call an update back to the UI.

The other solution would be to use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) which will trigger a call back every *n* periods and is executed within the Event Dispatching Thread...

Something like...

```
Timer dealerTimer= new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionListener(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (Dealer.getInstance().dealerPoints < 17) {
            Dealer.getInstance().openCard();
        } else {
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
dealerTimer.setRepeats(true);
dealerTimer.start();
```

What I would do, is declare `dealerTimer` as a class field.  When required, I would simply call `dealerTimer.restart()` to get the timer to restart.  You might also want to check `dealerTimer.isRunning()` to make sure that the timer isn't already running ;)

You might like to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some more information

Comment: No.  I'd probably make it apart of your `Dealer` class and wrap it's functionality up in a method call of some kind, something like, `showHand`.  That way if you want to change the implementation, the rest of the program won't suffer from it

Answer (score 0):

You could use: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long).  Put it in a try-except block.

```
// To wait 1 second:
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Not working @nair.ashvin. Edited first post with tentative code

Comment: I noticed you used 100 instead of 1000, is that on purpose? Also, did you `import java.lang.Thread;`

Comment: You've begin caught in the "answering without context" trap.  This isn't going to work (well) with the updated question

Comment: I have imported `java.lang.Thread;` now... But still it doesn't open the cards one by one as I supposed it should work

Comment: @nair.ashvin apparently the problem is with repaint(). This worked:

`while (i < 3){

    System.out.println(i); i++;
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){ }
   }`

The 100 was just because I was trying different intervals...

Answer (score 0):

go to sleep for a bit

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch (InterruptedException e){
   LOG.warning("unexpected interruption while sleeping");
}
```

Comment: You've begin caught in the "answering without context" trap.  This isn't going to work (well) with the updated question

Comment: I apologize. I'm new here in Stack Overflow.