# Wait one second after click and change JLabel icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, delay, jlabel

I am working on my first Swing application. It is a memory game using poker cards.

I simulate cards using `JLabel`s and setting icons for front and back sides. Each card has a `MouseListener` and when the user clicks, I check if two cards are the same. If they aren't the same card, I want to show these two cards for one or two seconds and after this delay, change icon back.

I tried using `sleep`, `wait`, `invokeLater`, `invokeAndWait`... but nothing works.

This is my main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException, IOException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  MyApp window = new MyApp();
              } catch ( FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
                  Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
          }
        });
    }
}
```

`MyApp` inherits from `JFrame`. Inside it, I add all my cards to one panel:

```
while ( cont < cardsInGame.size() ){            
        this.cardsInGame.get(cont).setBounds(x, y, 100, 140);
        panelTablero.add(cardsInGame.get(cont));
        cardsInGame.get(cont).addMouseListener(this);

        x = x+108+5;
        if ( (cont+1)%8 == 0 && cont != 0){
            y = y+140+15;
            x = 53;
        }
        cont++;
}
```

And this is the MouseListener:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    Card selectedCard = (Card)e.getSource();

    if (selectedCard != activeCard){
        selectedCard.setIcon(new ImageIcon("img/"+selectedCard.getSuit()+selectedCard.getValue()+".png"));

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vp, "Wait");

        if ( activeCard != null && !activeCard.getPaired()) {
            int result = activeCard.isPair(selectedCard);
            pairsTried++;
            if ( result != 0 ){
                // PAIR
            }
            else{
                // I WANT TO WAIT HERE
                // NO PAIR
                selectedCard.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CARD_BACK));
                activeCard.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CARD_BACK));
            }
            activeCard = null;
        }
        else{
            activeCard = selectedCard;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put a call to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vp, "Wait")` in my code, all works well. The icon is refreshed and after that wait for dialog OK. If not, the icon never is refreshed (or is ultra fast and is not showing).

How can I add this delay?

Comment: Use a Swing Timer. When the Timer fires you reset the icon.

Comment: Also, as a possible [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617871/open-card-after-certain-time/13618136#13618136)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. The example is perfect for me. I have tried in my app and it works!

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried to put a therad inside this else?

```
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        };
        Thread asd = new Thread(r);
        asd.start();
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(2000);`  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: As suggested by the two examples linked in the comments ;)